# SoapServer parsing string '<' to &lt; in the response while using SoapUI

Tags: php, soap, soapui, soapserver

I am working on a SOAP project and the response is not as expected instead I am getting in this format with &lt; in place of '<'

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:testResponse>
         <testname>
            //some other elements
            <description>&lt;![CDATA[Testing some 
data here]]&gt;</descripton>
            //some other elements
         </testname>
      </ns1:testResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using PHP as my soap handling and sending the data[name, description, location, etc.] through an instance which will be processed in the WSDL file with

My WSDL file represents the same element

```
 //other stuff  
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs='xyz' xmlns:xsd='abc'>
    <xs:complexType name="data">
        <xs:element name='name' type='xsd:string' />
        <xs:element name='description' type='xsd:string' />
        <xs:element name='location' type='xsd:string' />
        ....
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I even tried sending the data as a SoapVar like so in my PHP function

```
$this->description = new SoapVar("<![CDATA[".$res['info']."]]>", XSD_ANYTYPE);
```

and if I change it to XSD_ANYXML, the response is sending the data as plain text without the CDATA enclosure.

```
<name>myName</name>
Testing some
data here
<location>myLocation</location>
```

Can anyone help me find the error, I am new to using SOAP?

Comment: Try `new SoapVar("<anytag><![CDATA[{$xmlContent}]]></anytag>", XSD_ANYXML);`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @volkerschulz, however when I use the approach you have mentioned. I am able to get the tag name but the data is not considered as CDATA but is converting to some unreadable format as below, why is that?
The information is something like Ä | Ö | Ü | ß or so


```<anyTag>Testin ���
���
�
</anyTag>```

Comment: That is after the result has been parsed? Looks like an (unrelated) encoding problem to. Make sure it's UTF-8 and that the headers reflect that.